# Focus an HTML5 <button> element

Tags: jquery, html, button, focus

How can I focus an HTML5 `<button>` element (preferrably with jQuery)?

I have tried:

```
$('#myButton').focus();
```

and

```
$('#myButton').trigger('focus');
```

I tried it with and without a `tabstop` on the button, and no luck so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I was trying to focus the button from within another event handler (which apparently doesn't work).

My solution was to add a simple 1ms timeout:

```
window.setTimeout(function () { $('#myButton').focus(); }, 1);
```

This makes it work perfectly.

Comment: That seems like a bit of a workaround, if you post some code, perhaps there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: @Grezzo There's too much elaborate code to paste, 99% of it would be irrelevant (and I don't feel like obfuscating it to post it here). Suffice it to say the `.focus()` call originates from a `WebSocket` event, nested about 4 or 5 calls down the stack. For whatever reason, the combination of events/calls I have didn't allow a `.focus()` to be triggered right there.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me in Chrome 20 on XP: http://jsfiddle.net/Grezzo/KCS9T/

Comment: I said `<button>`, not `<input type="button">`. There *is* a difference, and I know it works with `<input>`.

Comment: aha, didn't spot that. sorry.